# Could not download Node.js from: https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/x64/node.exe: Got error code 404 from the server

Tags: node.js, maven, spring-boot

When i tried build and clean my project

*pom.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <nodeVersion>v6.11.3</nodeVersion>
    <npmVersion>3.10.10</npmVersion> 
    <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
    <workingDirectory>src/main/angularDash</workingDirectory>
</configuration>
```

I have this error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.22:install-node-and-npm
>   (install node and npm) on project dashAngular: Could not download
>   Node.js from: https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/x64/node.exe: Got error
>   code 404 from the server. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure below URL directly to download node

https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/win-x64/node.exe

Or if you replace version with v0.9.9 it will work

Comment: Try to change the node version to v0.9.9

Comment: thx for reply, I tried but it's not work 
new error : Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.22:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project dashAngular: Could not download Node.js from: https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/win-x64/node.exev6.11.3/x64/node.exe: Got error code 404 from the server

Comment: <configuration> <nodeVersion>v0.9.9</nodeVersion> <npmVersion>3.10.10</npmVersion> <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot> <workingDirectory>src/main/angularDash</workingDirectory> </configuration>



Just use above code it should work

Comment: Please let us know how to configure the URL to directly download node js.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of frontend-maven-plugin doesn't support newer chips. Especially, I got this error in my M1 Pro based MacBook.

The solution is to upgrade the plugin to 1.11.

Answer Courtesy: https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/m1-mac-cant-build-wknd-tutorial-get-quot-could-not-download-node/td-p/399462

Comment: This is most likely the solution if you've switched from Windows to Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
            <execution>
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.16.3</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.11.3</npmVersion>
                    <nodeDownloadRoot>http://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                    <npmDownloadRoot>http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
```

I replace the nodeDownloadRoot and npmDownloadRoot to `http` instead of `https`

Answer (score 0):

2023 UPDATE

Version 1.11.0 didn't fix to my M1 macOS. But version 1.12.1 did it!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my searching there seem to be a few reasons for this.

I had this issue when doing 'mvn clean install' at the top directory for the project archetype.

It was resolved for me when I first did 'mvn clean install' in the ui.frontend directory, and upon successful completion running it again the parent directory.